# Django PREFETCH_RELATED - only first element shown in template

Tags: django

I use prefetch_related to get reverse relation rows. Everything works fine with the only exception that I get only one of many relations. Better explained by example.

Model:

```
class Tasks(models.Model):
    #...

class TaskResponsiblePeople(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('Tasks', related_name='task_responsible_people')
```

View:

```
def showTasks(request):
   tasks = Tasks.objects.prefetch_related('task_responsible_people').all()
   return render_to_response('task_management/task_list.html',
                         {'responsible_people_form':responsible_people_form,
                          'tasks':tasks},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

{% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                {% for resp in task.task_responsible_people.all %}
                    <li>{{resp.auth_user.first_name}}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem here is that for one of the tasks I have several responsible people, but still get only on of them. Is it because I have to use the prefix "_set" somewhere in the code? If I do, I end up with an error message

Comment: Do you get the same result if you remove `prefetch_related()` from the queryset (you should get the same result but more queries). My guess is the problem is elsewhere - for example the task doesn't really have multiple responsible people, or one of `{{ resp.auth_user }}` or `{{ resp.auth_user.first_name }}` is empty.

Comment: Stupid question, I've just seen that I got connected to other database )